# How to sum values of columns if they have some row values in common in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, sum, aggregate

I have a very big dataframe. let df below represent it:

```
df <-as.data.frame(rbind(c("a",1,1,1),c("a",1,1,1),c("a",1,1,1),c("b",2,2,2),c("b",2,2,2),c("b",2,2,2)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
[2,] "a"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
[3,] "a"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
[4,] "b"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[5,] "b"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[6,] "b"  "2"  "2"  "2"
```

I want to create a dataframe like the one below out of it:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,] "a"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
 [2,] "b"  "6"  "6"  "6"
```

I see several similar posts here, but the answers although very useful need a vector pf all possible values in the first column and so on. my problem is my dataset has about 3000 rows.

How can I get the result in r?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `group_by`and `summarise`after using `type.convert(as.is=TRUE)`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(V1) %>% 
    summarise(across(V2:V4, sum))
```

```
  V1       V2    V3    V4
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 a         3     3     3
2 b         6     6     6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate`

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
aggregate(.~ V1, df, FUN = sum)
```

-ouptut

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  3  3  3
2  b  6  6  6
```

---

NOTE: The OP created the data.frame from a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class.  Thus, do the type conversion first

Answer (score 1):

Another `aggregate` option

```
> aggregate(. ~ V1, df, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  3  3  3
2  b  6  6  6
```